# What is the state of matter of a (solid) yogurt?

Tags: solid-state-physics

Consider a solid yogurt. Can we assign a specific state of matter to it?

I mean, it behaves like solid. However, if we "mix" it with a spoon, it becomes liquid, or at least in the usual sense. It is also quite plastic, which complicates.

My current guess is that it is either a glass or a gel, but I'm quite unsure about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thickness of yoghurt is due to bacteria producing lactic acid and flocculating the casein molecules. There's an excellent article on this [here](http://www.ajas.info/pdf/23-149.pdf).

We normally reserve the word *gel* for systems that display a yield stress. There are *set yoghurts* that would be described as a gel, but the more liquid yoghurts are just a [non-Newtonian fluid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid).

Answer (score -3):

Ice is able to "flow" under stress [as in glaciers], but is classified as a solid. Therefore, it seems safe to think that yogurt is a solid, too, as it flows when moved, but, does not flow on its own unless it is thin.